# Why doesn't my log4net appender create a file each day in year-month-day structure

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm trying to get log4net to log to files in a specific folder structure.
[logfolder]/year/month/day_file.log

With the configuration I have now, the initial log file is perfect. It creates the year and month folder and starts with the correct file. 
The problem is that it does not create new files in my desired structure each next day, but it creates a new file by appending the new date to the first log file name. As you can see, it now also does not create the desired month folders.

What I get now is this:

```
└───2018
    └───03
            28-03-2018_myLogFile.log
            28-03-2018_myLogFile.log28-03-2018
            28-03-2018_myLogFile.log29-03-2018
            28-03-2018_myLogFile.log30-03-2018
            28-03-2018_myLogFile.log31-03-2018
            28-03-2018_myLogFile.log01-04-2018
            28-03-2018_myLogFile.log02-04-2018
```

But what I need it this:

```
└───2018
    ├───03
    │       28-03-2018_myLogFile.log
    │       29-03-2018_myLogFile.log
    │       30-03-2018_myLogFile.log
    │       31-03-2018_myLogFile.log
    │
    └───04
            01-04-2018_myLogFile.log
            02-04-2018_myLogFile.log
            03-04-2018_myLogFile.log
```

The configuration I have now is this:

```
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="App_Data/log/%date{yyyy}/%date{MM}/%date{dd-MM-yyyy}_myLogFile.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %M - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

What did I do wrong? Or should I solve this by writing my own appender?

Comment: On a Windows OS, you'd be wise to avoid path parsing bugs in log4net by using backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, but I have to give credit to @sgmoore, though the answer was not complete.
The following solution creates a file in a ../log/yyyy/MM/dd-MM-yyyy_myLogFile.log structure. This version works better than the proposed version by @sgmoore.

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="App_Data/log/" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy/MM/dd-MM-yyyy'_myLogFile.log'" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %M - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="App_Data/log/%date{yyyy}/%date{MM}/" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy'_myLogFile.log'" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %M - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I have changed the `file type` and `datePattern` values and added a line to set `staticLogFileName` false.

Comment: Looking good so far. Thanks!
I will test this setting the coming period and will accept the answer if it works as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, Log4Net did not create a new 'month' folder for the month of May, '05'. New 'day' files were added nicely, but they were added to the '04', April folder. So, now my log file structure has 'May' files in the 'April' folder.
Is it possible, out of the box, to achieve the desired behavior I want?

Comment: By the way, this happens when the application (a Windows Service) is running for several days/weeks. Each time the application starts, the log file will be created in the correct folder.

Comment: So (if possible) you should add an automatic service restart every midnight

Comment: Just a thought .... instead of a server restart each night, is it not perhaps possible to get log4net to reread its config daily?

Comment: @earthling42 do you found any way of doing this ?

Comment: @mukesh kudi - unfortunately not, but I did not look very hard.